# Footer align image in center

Tags: html, css

I have image inside of that footer,I need to align image in  center and need to bring top from the footer and it must adjust to all the mobile device.IF i give **margintop** the image is stay in same place but footer height reduce below is my code

```
<footer data-role="footer">
    <center>
 <img src="images/image1.png" style="width:40px;height:40px;margin-top:20px"/>
      </center>
      </footer>
```

Comment: Pretty sire center tag is deprecated, your going to want to use flex box.

Comment: display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; works too to position something in center :-)

Comment: and have a look at display: table; ! That is useful for most positioning stuff too and has perfect browsersupport

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flex to achieve your goal, you can adjust footer height to whatever value you like but the image stay still in middle

```css
footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: violet;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<footer data-role="footer">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" />
      </footer>
```

Comment: thanks for your time, I need half of the image should be inside the footer and reaming half should outside

Answer (score 0):

**centered with flexbox**

```css
body {  /* ignore, for demo */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal align */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black; /* ignore, for demo */
}
img {
  height: 40px; width: 40px;  /* ignore, for demo */
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<footer data-role="footer">
 <img src="images/image1.png">
</footer>
```

**centered with text-align**

```css
body {  /* ignore, for demo */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black; /* ignore, for demo */
}
img {
  display: inline-block; /* centered by text-align on parent */
  height: 40px; width: 40px;  /* ignore, for demo */
  transform: translateY(50%); /* half below footer */
  /* overflow: hidden; turn this on if hiding the bottom half */
}
```

```html
<footer data-role="footer">
 <img src="images/image1.png">
</footer>
```

**centered with left: and transform: translate**

```css
body {  /* ignore, for demo */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black; /* ignore, for demo */
}
img {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%); /* centered */
  bottom: -20px; /* half below bottom, based on img height */
  height: 40px; width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<footer data-role="footer">
 <img src="images/image1.png">
</footer>
```